# PHP: Foreach an array won't output

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

When I dump the variable it has a data:

> var_dump($result);
>
> object(stdClass)#2 (5) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(6) "user_name" ["email"]=> string(14) "test@mail.com" ["password"]=> string(32) "password" ["test"]=> string(1) "1" }

But when I use foreach no value has return except if I just echo $data; but I want to be specific to the value I want to get.

> foreach($result as $data){
>
> echo $data->use_id;
>
> echo $data->username;
>
> }

Why there is no returned value?

Comment: use `echo $data->user_id` not `echo $data->use_id;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over the object. Just do this.

```
echo $result->user_id;
echo $result->username;
```

With the sample you provided you are treating each property in `$result` as an object and looking for `user_id` and `user_name` (which don't exist).

Comment: only it is actuall username,and not user_name. user_name is value. Look:  ["username"]=> string(6) "user_name"

Comment: Thank you. Don't know that yet. :D

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote:

> ```
> var_dump($result);
> ```

```
object(stdClass)#2 (5) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(6) "user_name" ["email"]=> string(14) "test@mail.com" ["password"]=> string(32) "password" ["test"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

So the result is an object itself. so if you want specify and fetch exact variable, there's no need to iterate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `json_decode` converts json string to array. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$array  = json_decode($result, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

You can use  foreach to `$array` and echo the result.